# Make java logging at the same folder of the JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

How to make java logging at the same folder of the JAR?

Thank you!

```
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Worker {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Logging begins...");    

         try {

             throw new Exception("Simulating an exception");
          } catch (Exception ex){
             logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
          }

         logger.info("Done...");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Handler` for the Logger you're using. `FileHandler` is particularly good here:

```
Handler h = new FileHandler("my-log.log");
h.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter()); //set format to what you normally see
logger.addHandler(h);
```

It will use the system property `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` for formatting the text, so you can either adjust the property to your use, or implement `Formatter` and set one yourself.

An example using the property would be:

```
"[%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS] %4$s: %5$s%n"
```

Which is a format I commonly see.

Comment: Basically it is correct. I found this example http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.util.logging.FileHandler amd this docs page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html